# Python script to check Namenode status

Tags: python, hadoop

I am new to Python and currently only learned a few things by researching online. Just wanted to know why am i getting "error" as the output rather than "success". Please see code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/python -v

import os
import subprocess

f = os.popen("hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn2")
now = f.read()
status = "active"
if now == status:
        print "success"
else:
        print 'error'
```

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: can you do `print now` instead of `print 'error'` and let us know what the output is?

Comment: To be safer you should probably do if `now.strip() == status`

Comment: #! /usr/bin/python -v

import os

f = os.popen("hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn2")
now = f.read()
print now
status = "active"
print status
if now == status:
        print "success"
elif now >= status:
        print "elif success"
else:
        print "error"

Comment: The output of print now = active. I added an elif statement as mention above and got output as "elif success". What i am trying to understand is that the code is pretty straight forward or atleast it seems to me, but why doesn't it print "success"

Comment: i will try now.strip() == status Donald. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You don't need to declare the status = "active" either.

Answer (score 0):

(moving comment to an answer)

Whenever pulling text from something like popen or anywhere, I like to use `.strip()` and usually `.lower()` to clean off the newlines and extra spaces.

```
#! /usr/bin/python -v

import os
import subprocess

f = os.popen("hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn2")
now = f.read().lower().strip()  # add strip here

if now == "active":
        print "success"
else:
        print 'error:', now  # why not print out what it output?
```